# Betas for robust regression using lmrob (robustbase package)

Tags: r, regression, beta, robust

R question: Is there a command I can run to get standardized beta values for a robust regression run using lmrob from the robustbase package? I am aware that I can easily obtain betas if I'm using lmRob from the robust package, but I prefer to use lmrob.